# How to include CSS/SCSS files now ImportMap is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

So unless I can not Google properly I can't find a definitive 'best practice' way to use Vendor styling in Rails 7.

It's the same with everything but say I am including Froala Editor and I include the JS through ImportMap and everything is great.

The way that I have found to include the styling for it though is to download the CSS and put it in a /vendor folder in my stylesheets directory and then include it.

Surely I am missing something simple...

Comment: I have been struggling with this as well. My project already has tailwindcss-rails installed, but I am now unsure where and how to add other npm projects that have their own css files to my project.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I am adding css files

1. Create a vendor/stylesheets folder
2. Modify config/initializers/assets.rb and add
   `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "stylesheets")`

Then

1. Download css files into vendor/stylesheets folder (you may need to create the stylesheets folder)
2. Add to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "cssfile.min", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>`

Comment: This solution works for Importmaps but I had to add ```//= link_tree ../../../vendor/stylesheets``` to the config/manifest.js file